# Where to look into the android source for Process life cycle management in Android system?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Can someone give pointers to the android source files to understand the Process life cycle management in android system.

And give idea about how processes are being managed between Linux kernel and android system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frameworks/base is where you should start:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git

Take the logcat from your device and then search for some logs related (i.e. ActivityManager) tags on the source code and so on...